# Is it natural to say "being happy for you"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

It's surely natural to say "I’m happy for you" and [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being%20happy%20for%20you%2C%20I%E2%80%99m%20happy%20for%20you&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20happy%20for%20you%3B%2Cc0) justifies it.

How about "I’m being happy for you"?  Is it natural to say that? If yes, in what situations?

Answer (score 1):

"I'm being happy for you" means I behave happily for you. It normally implies that my being happy is contrived and not genuine; but that's not necessarily always the case.

Comment: More generally, _I'm being happy/angry/sad_ is not usual, and so if people do use it it tends to have a special meaning, such as the meaning that @user178049 picked out in this answer.